# Effective debugging Ionic in the browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

As an Ionic Developer, how do you proceed with browser debugging?

I have been working with Ionic for a few weeks now, and although I am getting around its design, I am still struggling when it comes to debugging.

In most cases, a very generic, non-verbosed error is returned from the ionic framework, and none of the information provided in the stacktrace ever points to my own source code (see example below). I don't even know where to start.

> Error: node is undefined
>       compile/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20673:1
>       forEach@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13648:11
>       compile@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20672:7
>       generateNavBarItem@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:58872:14
>       self.beforeEnter@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:58811:26
>       $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29404:15
>       ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.emit@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:55182:13
>       ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.transition@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:55038:13
>       self.render/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56749:7
>       ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.init/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54916:25
>       ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.render@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:55005:23
>       ionicViewSwitcher.create/switcher.init@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54915:11
>       self.render@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56743:5
>       self.register@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56701:5
>       updateView@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62357:11
>       .compile/http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62334:11
>       $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29477:15
>       transitionTo/$state.transition<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:49321:11
>       processQueue@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27879:28
>       scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27895:27
>       $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29158:16
>       $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28969:15
>       $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29263:13
>       timeout/timeoutId<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:31030:25
>       completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18706:7
>       Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18978:7

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the JavaScript you can also use [Debugging with breakpoints (Debugging JavaScript)](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). This will help you a lot.

[image]

More about debugging: [How to Properly Debug Your Ionic Application](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-properly-debug-your-ionic-application/).

Comment: Useful link. This said, JavaScript debugging apart, I think the Ionic 1.x framework lacks verbosing when it comes to debugging.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is few tips that helps you in debugging**

1.use `ionic serve -l` for an emulator web view then go to inspect element find `console` it shows you all the errors occurred in you
    app

2.Attached your smartphone and use `chrome://inspect` to inspect your application

3.`ionic run -lc`